# Run VisualStudio classes (unit tests) from Excel?

Tags: excel, visual-studio, selenium

Might be a silly question, but: Is it possible? For example, click a button in Excel that runs a specific C# unit test in VS, preferably also sending some info from Excel, and possible getting back the result of the run.

I've been doing this a lot in HP QTP/UFT, for running test cases. Now I'm using Selenium in C#/VS, and was thinking maybe there was a way to "streamline" it here too.

I'm using VS 2013 Express, btw - if there are possibilities for this, I realize they might be limited or non-existant in the Express version.

Comment: Using Excel to organize tests and test data is a good way to create a "non-technical" user interface when using HP QTP/UTF. My question was if the same is possible with Excel and VS. That is, run the VS tests from Excel, getting the result back, and possibly also using test data from Excel in the VS tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized feature in any edition of Visual Studio that does this. One could build a plugin for Excel that does this. The [Visual Studio Test Runner is a simple executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) and it can output a XML file with the test results or you can attach your own logger (`/logger`) from the command line.

[VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx) allows you to write a plugin for Excel that can execute C# code. Running the test runner and parsing the results from C# code should be relatively straight forward.

To populate the list of available tests, you can use [`/ListTests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I'm not looking for a howto in this question, so I'm satisfied with a pointer towards how it can be done :-)